# Python csv sorting column TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, sorting

I'm trying to sort the csv data using Python built-in module but I facing this error and I'm not sure where goes wrong.

I'm using `key=lamda` to sort my column and `datetime` to sort my date column as ASC.

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
list_1 = list_1[3:]
list_2 = []

csv_writer.writerow(['date', 'student_number'])

for line in list_1:
new_row = [col for idx, col in enumerate(line) if idx not in (1, 4, 5, 8)]

    line2 = new_row
    list_2.append(line2)

student_num= sorted(list_2[:10], key=lambda row: (row['student_number'])) <-- error
date = sorted(csv_reader, key=lambda row: datetime.strptime(row['date'], "%m/%d/%Y"), reverse=True) <-- error
```

Comment: `row` is a list, what did you expect from `row['student_number')`?

Comment: I'm trying to sorting the header column base on ` row['student_number')'

Comment: But, as you're being told, that *isn't a thing you can sort on*; lists have integer indices, using a string like that would only work for a mapping type like a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a csv, the row sent back is not a dictionary but an array. In this instance getting the student_number information for the row is the array indice 1

Comment: Can you add some data example to understand better